# WebEngineView: image not loaded in a HTML when using 'loadHtml' with HTML content in a string

Tags: html, image, qtwebengine

I am using a WebEngineView to show messages (like a chat), with the help of a WebChannel.

I set a html from resources as url of the WebEngineView:

WebEngineView {
        id: myChat
        ...
        url: "qrc:/res/test.html"
        ...
   }

To display an image in my html, i add a 'div', for instance:

```html
<div class="file-thumbnail" style="background-image: url(file:///C:/Users/LocalUser/Diego/Local/Temp/Penguins.p‌​ng);"></div>
```

The thumb is displayed properly, since the file is available in this path

In one moment, i save all the html content into a string and restore it after a while using

myChat.loadHtml(text);

The html content is displayed properly except for the image, an error message appears in console:
    js: Not allowed to load local resource: file:///C:/Users/Diego/AppData/Local/Temp/Penguins.png

The image is still there, if I set this link in a real Chrome browser the image is open properly

Any idea? Thanks a lot in advance,

Diego

Answer (score 0):

I found it. It seems to be a problem with the WebEngineView  class and web security.

I had to add an argument to my QApplication a new argument: "--disable-web-security"

Now it works.

Diego